# how to take full page screenshot in chrome using selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium

In selenium tool, how to take full page screenshot and how to scroll the page?
If we use this code,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

it directly move to the bottom of the page.

Comment: It generally happens with chrome that only the visible part of the screen is saved as screenshot

Comment: one strategy is to first check whether the scroll bar is present or not , then if it is present then from its current position , first take the corordinates of the last point of screen , then in a loop scrool to that pont and again take a new screenshot , at last join all the screesnhot in a single file

Comment: let me know if you are okay with the approach then i will post the answer

Comment: Yes, i am okay with the approach.Please post the answer

Comment: posted a different answer , please hit the upward button

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver.exe"); 

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";

driver.get(baseUrl);        
String fullscreen =Keys.chord(Keys.F11);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(fullscreen);

TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)driver);  
File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);   
File DestFile=new File("F://test.png");  
FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);   
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, we need to download the ashot.jar file and add to the project along with the selenium jar files

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class TakeFullPageScreenShot
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",     "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

   driver.get("http://automationtesting.in/");
   Thread.sleep(2000);

   Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
   ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new                              
File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/ErrorScreenshots/FullPageScreenshot.png"));
 }
}
```

It will scroll the page to the end and captures the screenshot. And we can control the scroll speed using the viewportPasting method.

hope that helps

Comment: In Firefox it working fine, but in Chrome its not work, like half page

Comment: I ll have to check

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  @Test  public void f() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {Thread.sleep(2000);
  File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Vijaya\\selenium\\DF_007.png"));}

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: When we put above code in selenium, its redirecting to chrome but after that its not navigating mentioned URL

Answer (score 0):

Use the jar file of shutterbug in selenium. 
Here you can download the file : http://book2s.com/java/jar/s/selenium-shutterbug/download-selenium-shutterbug-0.4.html

And here is the command that will be placed in your code:

```
Shutterbug.shootPage(driver, ScrollStrategy.BOTH_DIRECTIONS).save("path to save image");
```

You dont need to handle any scrolls this is going to automatically capture full page screenshot